# Unidirectional rollers for a bookshelf door

Tags: furniture, hardware

I have a doorway about 4 feet high and a bookshelf that is a bit larger in both height and width than the doorway. I'd like to put hinges and rollers on the bookshelf unit to turn it into a hidden door.

I have in mind to use some rollers much like you find under a refrigerator that are linear (not omni-directional casters) and relatively wide (>2") to distribute the weight better and avoid creating impressions in my flooring from the heavy load. I can't seem to source these rollers or even determine what they're called. If anyone knows what to call them or where to find them online, I'd love some help.

I'm also open to other ideas to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Many diy / hardware stores carry wheels that would do this in various diameters.

Comment: **Fixed Casters** is the term you want. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fixed+casters&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ebayimg.com%2Fimages%2Fi%2F191928135822-0-1%2Fs-l1000.jpg

Comment: Thanks, Alaska Man (I grew up in Soldotna!)